# Paypal cert file to git

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, paypal

I follow the great rails cast [episode #143](http://railscasts.com/episodes/143-paypal-security) for PayPal security. Ryan suggests to create a certs file to Rails root and create a private key and a public certificate and then upload our certificate to PayPal and download their public certificate.

I have done these thinks, and my question is how can i pass this .pem files to heroku (i try with env variables but it doesn’t work). I'm using Figaro for hide sensitive data from my git.

Certs file contains these 3 files: app_cert.pem,  app_key.pem,  paypal_cert.pem 
and every one of them has a large password like this:

```
 -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
    MIICWwIBAAKBgQCor+6AnTxe0ma.....................
 -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: *i try with env variables but it doesn’t work* -- what and how exactly?

Comment: I solve it with direct declaration of the  env variables to heroku 's dashboard.  I would like to ask you if it is possible  to use `heroku config:set` to read the contents of a file.

Comment: [Sure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11918580/appending-file-contents-as-parameter-for-unix-shell-command).